# Automatically Delete Files/Folders

Tags: r, file, path, directory, delete-file

Is there any way to automatically delete all files or folders with few R command lines?
I am aware of the `unlink()` or `file.remove()` functions, but for those you need to define a character vector with exactly all the names of the files you want to delete.  I am looking more for something that lists all the files or folders within a specific path (e.g. 'C:/Temp') and then delete all files with a certain name (regardless of its extension).

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Maybe you're just looking for a combination of `file.remove` and `list.files`? Maybe something like:

```
do.call(file.remove, list(list.files("C:/Temp", full.names = TRUE)))
```

And I guess you can filter the list of files down to those whose names match a certain pattern using `grep` or `grepl`, no?

Comment: And possibly using the `pattern` argument to `list.files` (or `dir` which is a synonym). I think they produce a vector by default, so need to wrap a `list` call around them to work with `do.call`.

Comment: Guys,when I try the do.call like you said I get this error message: [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Warning messages:
1: In function (...)  :
  cannot remove file 'Sim2003.dbf', reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Which makes it seem like there is no file (there are no files) in the directory I specify...that is kinda weird since the files are there...and if I just use the list.files('C:/Temp') it gives me all the right ones...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I solved it...you need to add full.names=TRUE inside the list.files() function...otherwise it does not find them just with relative path...

Comment: You don't need `do.call`; see my answer.

Answer (score 86):

For all files in a known path you can:

```
unlink("path/*")
```

Comment: Why isn't this the highest voted solution? This works wonderfully.

Comment: One thing to note: this method deletes everything for good; files cannot be recovered within the recycling bin.

Comment: Best solution, but sometimes does not work. `recursive=TRUE` & `force=TRUE` helps. 
I am on linux.

Comment: This refuses to delete a directory in my windows 10 even with the recursive=TRUE and force=TRUE arguments. The structure of the directory is folder/folder/files, and I am trying to delete the top folder with unlink().

Comment: Any alternative that moves files to recycle bin/trash?

Answer (score 29):

```
dir_to_clean <- tempdir() #or wherever

#create some junk to test it with
file.create(file.path(
  dir_to_clean, 
  paste("test", 1:5, "txt", sep = ".")
))

#Now remove them (no need for messing about with do.call)
file.remove(dir(  
  dir_to_clean, 
  pattern = "^test\\.[0-9]\\.txt$", 
  full.names = TRUE
))
```

You can also use `unlink` as an alternative to `file.remove`.

Comment: What if I want to delete files for which their position indice doesn't show in a position indice vector? For example, the files are:a.txt, b.txt, c.txt and my vector v <- c(1, 3). The result should only show files:a.txt and c.txt

Comment: @Nanami: Read http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html and `?regex`.  If you are still stuck, then ask a question with the tag `regex`.

Comment: Thanks. I used this in my code though I ended up deleting the `^` and the `$` in my regex and I think this is the change that made it work. Can't say that I tested this thoroughly.

Comment: This is a great solution. Also works by just specifying the directory (for the edification of other less savvy R users like myself). "file.remove(dir(path = "01 Data/", pattern = "my_pattern", full.names = TRUE))

Answer (score 6):

To delete everything inside the folder, but keep the folder empty

```
unlink("path/*", recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
```

To delete everything inside the folder, and also delete the folder

```
unlink("path", recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
```

Use `force = TRUE`, to overwrite any read-only/hidden/etc. issues.

Answer (score 4):

Using a combination of dir and grep this isn't too bad.  This could probably be turned into a function that also tells you which files are to be deleted and gives you a chance to abort if it's not what you expected.

```
# Which directory?
mydir <- "C:/Test"
# What phrase do you want contained in
# the files to be deleted?
deletephrase <- "deleteme"

# Look at directory
dir(mydir)
# Figure out which files should be deleted
id <- grep(deletephrase, dir(mydir))
# Get the full path of the files to be deleted
todelete <- dir(mydir, full.names = TRUE)[id]
# BALEETED
unlink(todelete)
```

Comment: `dir` takes a `pattern` argument, so you don't need the separate use of `grep`.

Comment: @RichieCotton Good point.  I'll take note of that as I don't really use dir all that often and grep seemed like a natural solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like `here::here` for finding my way through folders (especially if I'm switching between inline evaluation and knit versions of an Rmarkdown notebook)... yet another solution:

```
    # Batch remove files
    # Match files in chosen directory with specified regex
    files <- dir(here::here("your_folder"), "your_pattern") 

    # Remove matched files
    unlink(paste0(here::here("your_folder"), files))
```