# how to delete a file with R?

Tags: r, file, file-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically Delete Files/Folders in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296377/automatically-delete-files-folders-in-r)

I would like to know if there is a way in R to check up if a file is in my current directory, and if it is there then the program deletes it?

I know that other languages have direct access to OS functions to do this task, but I am a little bit dubious if R has that capability.

Comment: Type `?system` at the console prompt.

Answer (score 183):

How about:

```
#Define the file name that will be deleted
fn <- "foo.txt"
#Check its existence
if (file.exists(fn)) {
  #Delete file if it exists
  file.remove(fn)
}
```

As far as I know, this is a permanent, non-recoverable (i.e. not "move to recycle bin") on all platforms ...

Comment: Any alternative that moves files to recycle bin/trash?

Comment: @duncanrager, I don't know of one.  You could ask a new question (after checking for other answers on StackOverflow, of course ...)

Comment: Stupid question: how are you able to execute the if() condition without the requisite {}?

Comment: curly brackets are not required if the code to be executed consists of a single statement (although arguably it would be best practice to include them anyway)

Comment: @derp92 Just to confirm. `file.remove(fullfilepath)` permanently deletes the file.

Answer (score 24):

One of the reasons R cannot be safely exposed to outside users is that it offers complete access to system facilities. In addition to the `list.files`, `list.dirs` and the `file.remove` functions, the `system` function allows access to pretty much any exploit imaginable.

Comment: I think the downvotes (not necessarily from @DWin) are because it shouldn't have been *too* hard to find these answers by googling/searching Stack Overflow. I don't actually think the link pointed to (which you would have found by searching SO for `[r] delete file`) is an exact duplicate, but it probably would have answered your question.

Comment: @BenBolker. A question gets closed as a duplicate i it cover the same material. The functions in your answer all appear immediately if one types `?files` at the command prompt. No googling needed. I suspect the downvotes are due both to the lack of any statement that a search of any sort was done and to the implied slur at R being limited in some way.