# Can I invoke linux shell commands in a R session?

Tags: r, bash

I am using RStudio and at times I want to remove some files in the working directory (e.g., previously generated .csv files).

It is quite inconvenient to frequently switch to bash and execute `rm`. Is there any way of invoking commands in the R console?

Comment: see `system` or `shell`

Comment: Also take a look at the [file manipulation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/files.html) documentation.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219887/how-to-delete-a-file-with-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/1550-how-do-i-run-a-system-command-without-using-the-shell)
Use system (or shell) as agstudy's comment says

e.g. `system("pwd")`

Answer (score 6):

If you are just removing files, rather than executing arbitrary commands on the shell, you would be better off following Thomas's suggestion:

```
?file.remove
```

Using this function instead of `shell("rm example.csv")` is safer and more portable.