# Recoverable file deletion in R

Tags: r

According to these questions:

1. [Automatically Delete Files/Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296377/automatically-delete-files-folders)
2. [how to delete a file with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219887/how-to-delete-a-file-with-r)

the two ways to delete files in R are `file.remove` and `unlink`. These are both permanent and non-recoverable.

Is there an alternative method to delete files so they end up in the trash / recycle bin?

Comment: can't you make a directory and just move them there and rm/restore them once decided?

Comment: ```library(filesstrings); file.move("C://Users//username//Documents//ex.png", "C://$Recycle.Bin")``` I tried this but seems *R* does not recognize recycle bin location. May be running something using powershell or cmd which is triggered by r?

Comment: Looking for a system agnostic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't know about a solution that is fully compatible with Windows' "recycle bin", but if you're looking for something that doesn't quite delete files, but prevents them from being stored indefinitely, a possible solution would be to move files to the temporary folder for the current session.

The command `tempdir()` will give the location of the temporary folder, and you can just move files there - to move files, use `file.rename()`.

They will remain available for as long as the current session is running, and will automatically be deleted afterwards . This is less persistent than the classic recycle bin, but if that's what you're looking for, you probably just want to move files to a different folder and delete it completely when you're done.

For a slightly more consistent syntax, you can use the `fs` package (https://github.com/r-lib/fs), and its `fs::path_temp()` and `fs::file_move()`.