# files still showing in finder after file.remove()

Tags: r, macos, file-io

`file.remove()` deletes my files, but they still appear in finder. Am I doing something wrong?

Some test code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296377/automatically-delete-files-folders-in-r):

```
file.create(file.path(
  "temp/", 
  paste("test", 1:5, "txt", sep = ".")
))

file.remove(dir(  
  "temp/", 
  pattern = "^test\\.[0-9]\\.txt$", 
  full.names = TRUE
))
```

After deleting:
[image]

Confirming deleted:
[image]

```
#sessionInfo()
#R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
#Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: sounds more like a  "refresh" problem with the Finder. Try this trick: change the display from List to Icons and back again (in the Finder window) and see if the deleted files are still there.

Comment: yeha I am definitely with Carl on that one, in Linux same happens. Refresh the window and the files will be probably gone.

Comment: thanks, @Carl. the trick worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from @Carl Witthoft: Try this trick: change the display from List to Icons and back again (in the Finder window) and see if the deleted files are still there.