# Deleting files in folder and its sub folders in R

Tags: r

In R I am trying to delete all the files in a folder and its sub folders. However, I want to keep the folders intact. What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296377/automatically-delete-files-folders?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fold <- 'C:/some/path/here'

# get all files in the directories, recursively
f <- list.files(fold, include.dirs = F, full.names = T, recursive = T)
# remove the files
file.remove(f)
```